# active bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i record a bag file , i need to end the record by myself with ctrl C.
this create a bag file with .active. i can't succeed to open it with rxbag.i tried rosbag reindex and that make a copy of that file which i also can't open with rxbag. how can i record a proper bag files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66316/active-bag-file/) by [shani](https://answers.ros.org/users/5288/shani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosbag play <file.bag>
```

---

Originally posted by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) with karma: 127 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sohel](https://answers.ros.org/users/32541/sohel/) on 2017-11-14**:
I repeat that, I don't have any .bag file. It creates a .bag.active file